# How to make a complex line in pure css?

Tags: css, line

i would like to make a pure css line inside a div, like the image bellow, is this possible?

[image: css line]

thanx

Comment: you tried something for that?

Comment: Do you have any `HTML` (content) associated with this line also?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to get started.

```css
.lineWrapper {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  padding: 30px;
}
.lineWrapper .line {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.lineWrapper .line:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="lineWrapper">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow...so many answers, thanx a lot...i have this until now, based on the answer above...i thought to use before: and after...but probably this is the easiest way to do it: 
https://jsfiddle.net/u8ywdx06/3/
because i want to control every item...so i have to optimize this...but i will look also to the other answers...

Comment: @AlexMatino : Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's expected that you try to implement and request for help when there is an issue. Always post the code what you have tried, so that people here would be happy to help. Happy Coding!